# Выдает всегда false

Tags: java

Вот задача Есть поле из клеток по средине которого находится робот. Робот умеет выполнять 4 команды: двигаться на 1 клетку в сторону: R (right), L (left), U (up), and D (down). Задана строка из движений робота например "UUDLDR". Написать метод который вернет true если робот вернется в ту же клетку с которой начал.

вот я пытался это сделать но всегда выдает false, подскажите как сделать задачу? Мое решение:

```
public class robot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[][] = new int[3][3];
        int nullength = 2;
        int nulweight = 2;
        int nextlenght = 0;
        int nextweight = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Клетки 3х3, движения вводить так 'U D L R', а иначе 
        работать не будет.");
        String move = s.nextLine();
        move.split(" ");

         System.out.println(moveRobot(nextlenght,nulweight,nullength,nextweight,
        move));

    }

    public static boolean moveRobot(int nullenght, int nulweight, int 
    nextlenght, int nextweight, String move) {

        if (move.split(" ").equals("U")) {
            nextweight = nextweight++1;
        }
        if (move.split(" ").equals("D")) {
            nextweight = nextweight+-1;
        }
        if (move.split(" ").equals("L")) {
            nextlenght = nextlenght-1;
        }
        if (move.split(" ").equals("R")) {
            nextlenght = nextlenght+1;
        }


        if (nextlenght == nullenght && nextweight == nulweight) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Что возвращает `move.split(" ")`, и как это может быть равно одной букве?

Comment: `nextlenght` -> `nextlength`

Comment: Не совсем уверен, но попробуй в сплит заменить " " на "" (пробел убери)

Comment: Если предполагается, что поле безграничное, то можно просто посчитать, сколько раз встречается каждый символ. Для возвращения в исходную точку необходимо и достаточно, чтобы количество "R" равнялось количеству "L", а количество "U" - количеству "D".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неправильная логика.

Сначала разберитесь, что делает функция [`split()`](http://proglang.su/java/strings-split), пока это выглядит как необдуманно скопированный кусок кода перед пересдачей.
`move.split(" ")` вообще закидывает всё в массив, которого у вас нет. В функцию `moveRobot` передаётся та же самая строка "UUDLDR", которую вы в дальнейшем сравниваете на **равенство** с буквами, что априори неправильно, поэтому по итогу работы функции вы увидите `false`.

Какова могла быть правильная логика:
Пройтись по строке посимвольно, если вверх - значит по Оси ушел на +1 вверх, аналогично с 3 другими буквами.
Итог - если по оси Х и У переменные будут 0.

```
public static boolean moveRobot(int nextlenght, int nextweight, String move) {
    for (int i = 0; i < move.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(Character.toString(move.charAt(i)));

        if (Character.toString(move.charAt(i)).equals("U")) {
            nextweight = nextweight + 1;
        }
        if (Character.toString(move.charAt(i)).equals("D")) {
            nextweight = nextweight - 1;
        }
        if (Character.toString(move.charAt(i)).equals("L")) {
            nextlenght = nextlenght - 1;
        }
        if (Character.toString(move.charAt(i)).equals("R")) {
            nextlenght = nextlenght + 1;
        }

    }

    if (nextlenght == 0 && nextweight == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Пример на [ideone](https://ideone.com/4mtkx7).

Answer (score 1):

В общем создай новую переменную `String[] spl;` и ей задай значение `move.split(" ");`

Потом все `if` занеси в цикл:

```
int num = 0;
while (num < spl.length){

}
```